# Multiple MS SQL queries on one table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

So I need some help, I have a MS Access database.  I have a table that I run about 4 queries on.  It takes about 5 min to open or save query 4 because it runs against 3, 2, and 1.  Even though it is running locally.  I was thinking that running it on a SQL server would go faster.  The question is, can I do the same thing on a SQL server?  Will I need to create stored procedures or is it even possible?

Comment: It's a rather vague question. If you had sample data and/or queries it would help.  It might need to be a stored procedure (which isn't that big of a deal) or there might be other options.

Comment: Tell us about these queries -- maybe we can consolidate them.

Comment: You might have better results if you save the first 3 query results to local temp tables.  Then let the 4th query work from those tables. This *might* speed things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad question, but I'll try to answer it.  Depending on how you build the SQL Server database, the queries will most likely run better on SQL Server.  However, you will have to build it *properly*.  In Access, you may even be able to just properly index or construct the tables and it might run fine.

Open a new question with actual SQL code and schema descriptions and maybe someone can help you just in Access.

Comment: I have two tables with test scores for reading and one for math.  There are four reading and math tests taken by over 2,000 students.  I need to find the growth for each student from test 1 to 2, then 1 to 3, then 1 to 4, and every other combination.  Then I need to find out which ones grew by at least one point.  Then group by grade and find out how many grew then do the same thing by building.  I can do that with Access but when I am trying to open or save any query that is running the calculations, it will take 5 min to respond even when the database is sitting on the local computer.

Comment: You need one table that is student, grade, and a foreign key int to another table that had a key and a field called TestName or something.  Either way, yes, SQL Server won't have the particular problem you're discussion, but it also won't look like a spreadsheet (where you edit).  If you're interested in design improvements, post another question asking for help with a database schema :)  it can potentially run fine in Access with correct design and indexed (sorry for poor grammar -- I'm on a phone)